# Chrome Extension: D3.js force-directed graph layout error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to create a Chrome Extension that maps a user's navigation and then creates a force-directed graph with the data.

In my `content.js`, I collect the data every time the page refreshes.
In `background.js`, I create a JSON object in the format shown below.
In `popup.js`, I want to create the graph.

The **JSON object** called `convertedInfo` looks as follows:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"index":[value],"anchor":[value], "url":[value]},
    {"index":[value],"anchor":[value], "url":[value]}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":[value],"target":[value]},
    {"source":[value],"target":[value]}
  ]
}
```

The manifest file used in the extension is as follows.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Navigation Visualisation",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Create a visualisation of your web navigation actions.",


    "browser_action":
      {
          "default_icon": "icon.png",
          "default_popup" : "popup.html",
          "default_title" : "Navigation Visualisation"
      },

     "background":
     {
        "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": false
     },

    "content_scripts":
      [
          {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"]

          }
      ],

    "permissions":
      [
        "activeTab", "storage"
      ]

}
```

`content.js` has the following line of code that sends on every page refresh:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'method':'setInfo'});
```

`popup.html` looks as follows:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<title> Navigation Visualisation</title>
<body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

<div id="container">  </div>
```

My code for the `D3.js` graph layout in `popup.js` is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  var convertedInfo = {};
  var count = 0;

  convertedInfo.nodes = [];
  convertedInfo.links = [];


  //listen for messages from content.js to update the data
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){

 if(message.method == 'setInfo')
 {
   convertedInfo.nodes.push({'index': count, 'anchor': count});
   if(count > 0)
   {
     convertedInfo.links.push({'source': count-1, 'target': count});
   }
   count++;

   runVisualisation();
 } 

});  

function runVisualisation()
  {
        d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
        var width = 500,
            height = 500;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-20)
            .linkDistance(10)
            .size([width, height])
            .nodes(convertedInfo.nodes)
            .links(convertedInfo.links)
            .start();


        var node = svg.selectAll("node")
          .data(convertedInfo.nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("r", 7)
          .attr("class", "node");

          //Adding links and data
        var link = svg.selectAll("link")
          .data(convertedInfo.links)
          .enter()
          .append("line")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("stroke", "grey");

        force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

          node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });
  }

});
```

My graph is showing, but not properly. One of the nodes is always half hidden outside the `svg` area and I get thousands of errors in the console saying the following:

```
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x1="NaN" d3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y1="NaN" d3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute x2="NaN" d3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <line> attribute y2="NaN" d3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="NaN" d3.min.js:1
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN" d3.min.js:1
```

But when I output the JSON object, I can clearly see all the `x`, `y`, `weight` etc attributes that have been automatically added and as far as I can see, they do not seem strange at all.

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/k0rhLeae/

Comment: I left out the section of code where I remove the whole `svg` element and re-run the code every time the JSON object is updated from background.js. Is that likely to cause an error?

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing it.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question to show all the code on the page. I replaced the incoming JSON object with a simple structure that I simply push values onto every time a page is clicked. This was to see whether the problem lay in my data, which it didn't. The errors only display when certain nodes are added - I've noticed it's often the 2nd and 5th and I am really not sure why.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: I have added my manifest file for the extension; the line of code in `content.js` that sends the message to `popup.js` and the code inside `popup.html`. That should be everything needed to reproduce the problem as `background.js` collects and stores the data but because I have temporarily replaced that structure with the JSON structure manually created in `popup.js`, it shouldbe fine. I hope this is everything. Really appreciate the help

Comment: Ah, don't use several force layouts, they will interfere. Re-use the same one: http://jsfiddle.net/u3msjjbt/